# Deal with standard library types in scope of dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dependency-injection

Consider the following type:

```
class SomeType
{
    public void Configure()
    {
        var windowsService = new ServiceController("msdtc");
        windowsService.Start();
    }
}
```

There are at least three issues.

1. We have implicit dependency to `ServiceController`.
2. We cannot to unit test `Configure()`.
3. We have a `new` operator that breaks our DI strategy.

So to fix it we can extract another type and input it to our `SomeType`.

```
interface IWindowsService
{
    void Start();
}

class WindowsService : IWindowsService
{
    private readonly ServiceController _serviceController;
    public WindowsService(string serviceName)
    {
        _serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceName));
    }

    public void Start() => _serviceController.Start();
}

class SomeType
{
    private readonly IWindowsService _msdtcService;
    public SomeType(Func<string, IWindowsService> createServiceCallback) //explicit dependency
    {
        _msdtcService = createServiceCallback.Invoke("msdtc");
    }

    public void Configure() => _msdtcService.Start();
}
```

It fixes the issues #1 and #2 but we still have a `new` operator in the new type `WindowsService`. I try to understand *should I register standart `ServiceController` in the DI-container or use it directly as demonstrated above (by `new`)?*

```
container.RegisterType<ServiceController>();
```

Also I am not sure *whether we should try to test `WindowsService`* or maybe it would be better to rewrite it something like this:

```
class WindowsService : ServiceController, IWindowsService
{
}
```

Since `WindowsService` is now just inheriting we cannot test anything here. The type is already tested by Microsoft.
However it breaks incapsulation and maybe ISP from SOL**I**D. Because we can cast `IWindowsService` to `WindowsService` or even to `ServiceController`.

What is the best way to deal with standart stable types?
Please refer me to another question if we have.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    void Configure();
}

class SomeType : ISomeInterface
{
    public void Configure()
    {
        var windowsService = new ServiceController("msdtc");
        windowsService.Start();
    }
}
```

I would do it like above. Now nothing should directly depend on `SomeType`. Everything should depend on `ISomeInterface`. That keeps the dependency on `ServiceController` limited to a single class.

The `new` operator really isn't a problem. There's no `IServiceController` that `ServiceController` implements, so if you want to use it, you have to tie yourself to it. By hiding it in `SomeType` which does implement an interface, at least you've limited how many things have a direct dependency on it.

Comment: Okay, from your point I do not need to register ServiceController in the di-container and can preserve implicit dependency, right?

Comment: @Serg046 Right. Could you register ServiceController? Probably. But there's not much point since `SomeType` will always depend on it.

Comment: Understood, then looks like I need to preserve `SomeType` is very small and produce business logic as small as possible because it can not be unit tested. Point up and will wait for a while for some other points.

Comment: About "There's no IServiceController that ServiceController implements". Yes, but we can add it by adding `interface IServiceController { void Start() }`
and then `class CustomServiceController : ServiceController, IServiceController {}`.

Comment: @Serg046 But what advantage does that give you? You're still depending on `ServiceController`.

Comment: Why? Now I can be dependent to `IServiceController`. But I am not sure if this is really advantage. At least it will allow unit testing so we can add some business logic to original `SomeType`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are dealing with is a subtype of a larger problem, the issue of dealing with system level calls in IoC.

Another example of the problem is the use of `DateTime.Now`.  If you call this in your code, there is no way to isolate it away, which is a problem if you want to test in various time scenarios.

One solution is to abstractify away all system level calls, so that you can substitute your own mock operating system for the purpose of testing. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899680/how-to-use-a-di-ioc-container-with-the-model-binder-in-asp-net-mvc-2) is an example for DateTime.  I'll provide an example for your specific issue too:

```
interface IOperatingSystem
{
    void StartService(string name);
}

class OperatingSystem : IOperatingSystem
{
    public virtual void StartService(string name) {
        var windowsService = new ServiceController(name);
        windowsService.Start();
    }
}

class SomeType : ISomeType
{
    private readonly IOperatingSystem _operatingSystem;

    public SomeType(IOperatingSystem operatingSystem)
    {
        _operatingSystem = operatingSystem;
    }

    public void Configure()
    {
        _operatingSystem.StartService("msdtc");
    }
}
```

In your IoC container:

```
container.RegisterType<IOperatingSystem, OperatingSystem>();
container.RegisterType<ISomeType, SomeType>();
```

Now you can isolate away all you want, just by overriding your operating system class:

```
class MockOperatingSystem : OperatingSystem
{
    public override StartService(string name)
    {
        //Do something worthy of testing, e.g. return normally or throw an exception
    }
}
```

and register (in your unit tests) like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IOperatingSystem, MockOperatingSystem>();
```

Now when you go to code this, you might choose to have different interfaces for different system functions (e.g. maybe you want a `IServiceControlManager` that is separate from other O/S calls). That is fine, and common. I prefer one big class for all my O/S calls, because I know those O/S calls are not going to change. Well, they might change, but if they do, I have much bigger problems, and rework will be unavoidable anyway.

Comment: But you just rewrite my words. What is the key difference between your `OperatingSystem` and my `WindowsService` (first version)? It looks the same. Also for mock purpose we do not need a virtual method because we can mock just interface. Anyways thank you for your time and point.

Comment: What can I say? I like your solution.

Comment: What about the second version of `WindowsService`? Have you seen something like that? It looks more preferable for me because we do need to use `new` operator and nothing to unit test here. However in the first version we can want to unit test `WindowsService.Start()` although of course it looks strange.